# Can someone please explain me this line of code

Tags: jquery

Can someone please explain me this line of code.

> 1. The use of '.btn'
> 2. Difference between jQuery() and $()

```
jQuery('.btn').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Did you try doing the jQuery tutorial ? Or simply reading the documentation ? I'm sorry but this is really too basic. Please have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Both jQuery and $ represents the same function it is just alias of same. I suggest you to go through jQuery tutorial. http://www.w3schools.com is a good website to start with. And Ofcourse as @dystroy stated  http://learn.jquery.com is also a very useful resource.

Answer (score 3):

1. `.btn` is a class selector, a shortcut for native
   `document.getElementsByClass()`, which get all elements with that class.
2. `$` is an alias for `jQuery`. Since you can have more frameworks that uses `$`, you could call jQuery by its name.

The line:

```
jQuery('.btn').trigger('click');
```

Means "*Get all elements with class 'btn' and trigger their click events"*.

I recommend you read @dystroy comment and take note of it.

Answer (score 2):

> The use of '.btn'

`.btn` is a CSS selector for elements with the class `btn`, like this:

```
<div class="btn">...</div>
```

(It could be any kind of element, doesn't have to be a `div`.)

> Difference between jQuery() and $()

There usually isn't any. `jQuery` and `$` both refer to the same function. But if you use jQuery's [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict), one or both of them may no longer refer to it.

The line of code is using [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) to find all such elements, and then using [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) to simulate a click on them.

Answer (score 0):

1. `.btn` is a `class selector` of `Jquery` Framework  . which means selecting  some element with class `btn`.
2. `$()` is a sort form of `jQuery()`. No difference actually.

   `jQuery('.btn').trigger('click');`

will trigger a click event on element with class `btn`. Which will effect as like if you click that element by your self with mouse.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.btn').trigger('click');
```

Above code calls the click event for the Class .btn from the document.

This will calls only when you have defined the click function in jquery.

Thanks